# Match character of two strings

Tags: android, string

I have two Strings 
String 1 = "In the name of God, the Gracious, the Merciful."
String 2 = "In the name of God the Gracious the Merciful"

I want to match each word of string two with string one. I have used below code but it's not working fine for above case

```
 private void printDiff(final Context context, String sentence1, String sentence2) {
        String[] array1 = sentence1.split(" ");
        String[] array2 = sentence2.split(" ");

        SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(sentence1);
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            int colorRes;
            if (i < array2.length) {

                    colorRes = array1[i].equalsIgnoreCase(array2[i]) ? R.color.colorPrimary : R.color.colorAccent;


            } else {
                colorRes = R.color.black;
            }
            int startIndex = getStartIndexOf(array1, i);
            int endIndex = startIndex + array1[i].length();
            sb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes)), startIndex, endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }


    } 

 public static int getStartIndexOf(String[] array, int index) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            count += array[i].length();
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Can anyone help me

I want output like this. Because all characters matched

[image]

Comment: Are you using fixed values for both String variables or they will change

Comment: they will change

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your String to character array and can match them by characters

```
s1 = s1.replacereplace(" ", "");
s1 = s1.replacereplace(",", "");

s2 = s2.replacereplace(" ", "");

  char[] a = s1.toCharArray(); 

  char[] b = s2.toCharArray();
  int j=0;
   for(int i=0; <a.length; i++){
        if(a[i]==b[j]){

         }
           j++;
    }
```

Comment: How can i generate output like above image ?

Answer (score -1):

try this code to check the differences of your string

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String string1 = "In the name of God, the Gracious, the Merciful.";
    String string2 = "In the name of God the Gracious the mercifuls";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(string2.split(" "))); // Split the string into list
        // compare the list with the source of the string, if match put into the list of result
        List<String> result = stringList.stream().filter(new Predicate<String>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(String s) {
//                return string1.contains(s); // case sensitive
                return Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(string1).find(); // case insensitive
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // check the match results
        if(result.size()<stringList.size()){
            Log.d("test", "onCreate: not match");
        }else{
            Log.d("test", "onCreate: match");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope can help you to resolve your problems

so in-order to use the code above needed to edit gradle. Open the app.gradle of yours and put this into your gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        .....
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            .....
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}
```

Comment: this is using java 8, i tested already and it's working, do you get error or the answer is not your expectation?

Comment: Can you tell me how can i generate output like above

Comment: I have edited the code and you needed to put some code into your gradle so you can use the code, please let me know if there are some problems occurred again

Comment: Your code is matching whole string. I want to match each word and then change the colour of each word